# Simple calculator crashes because of null pointer

Tags: java, android

I've just started to look at Android development and I followed a tutorial on how to make a super simple basic calculator (with just sum, sub, div and mult operations) but my APP is full of bugs and one of them is crashing when I do an operation without any inserted values.

This is just a portion of the code and I think the crash is in this part (for every button). How can I solve this issue without crashing the app? Like doing nothing when one TextEdit is blank? Do I need any throw/catch exception?

```
        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                firstNum = new BigDecimal(firstNumber.getText().toString());
                secondNum = new BigDecimal(secNumber.getText().toString());

                if (firstNum == null || secondNum == null) {
                    while (verificar) {
                    }
                } else {
                    result.setText(firstNum.subtract(secondNum).toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

The logcat.txt of the errors...
Thanks for your patience...

```
06-18 16:39:51.018: E/AndroidRuntime(621): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 16:39:51.018: E/AndroidRuntime(621): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Bad offset/length: offset=0 len=0 in.length=0
06-18 16:39:51.018: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:282)
06-18 16:39:51.018: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:438)
06-18 16:39:51.018: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at com.example.simplecalculator.Calculadora$1.onClick(Calculadora.java:44)
06-18 16:39:51.018: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
06-18 16:39:51.018: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
06-18 16:39:51.018: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-18 16:39:51.018: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-18 16:39:51.018: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-18 16:39:51.018: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-18 16:39:51.018: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 16:39:51.018: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 16:39:51.018: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-18 16:39:51.018: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-18 16:39:51.018: E/AndroidRuntime(621):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 16:41:07.109: E/Trace(644): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-18 16:41:09.339: E/AndroidRuntime(644): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 16:41:09.339: E/AndroidRuntime(644): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Bad offset/length: offset=0 len=0 in.length=0
06-18 16:41:09.339: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:282)
06-18 16:41:09.339: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:438)
06-18 16:41:09.339: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at com.example.simplecalculator.Calculadora$1.onClick(Calculadora.java:44)
06-18 16:41:09.339: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
06-18 16:41:09.339: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
06-18 16:41:09.339: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-18 16:41:09.339: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-18 16:41:09.339: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-18 16:41:09.339: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-18 16:41:09.339: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 16:41:09.339: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 16:41:09.339: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-18 16:41:09.339: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-18 16:41:09.339: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You could check the exception stack trace. What line is the error on, i.e. where do you get the nullpointer exception?

Comment: You really need to post the stack trace or we can't help you. Just by looking at it, you could have potential null pointers is `sub` is null, `firstNumber` is null, `secNumber` is null,  `result` is null, etc.

Comment: well, I dont know how to get the stack trace. And Im not 100% sure it's because of the null pointer, but if the values are empty it points to something null, right?

Comment: you can add logcat to check error.

Comment: If using Eclipse, Window-->Show View-->Android-->Logcat  Copy/paste the errors here

Comment: Filter the logcat once you get it shown by "Error" instead of "Verbose" and copy/paste that is what I meant. Edit the OP to add it...not in comments

Comment: Alternatively you can open the Debug or DDMS perspective. I usually click the toolbar button at the top right of the Eclipse window to open a new perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment of the BigDecimal will throw a NumberFormatException if the string is empty.  Change this:

```
firstNum = new BigDecimal(firstNumber.getText().toString());
secondNum = new BigDecimal(secNumber.getText().toString());
```

to this:

```
try {
    firstNum = new BigDecimal(firstNumber.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    firstNum = null;
}
try {
    secondNum = new BigDecimal(secNumber.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    secondNum = null;
}
```

Comment: and what about the if and the else? Remove them?

Comment: No, they're fine as is.  the problem is the line "firstNum = new BigDecimal("");".  BigDecimal's constructor throws an exception when you pass it any string that is not a number.  So, you want to catch that error, and assign firstNum to be null.  Or set it to 0, or pop up an error message, or whatever.

Comment: It can all be wrapped in one `try/catch` if you want. I would also suggest displaying a message in the `catch` instead of just making the variables `null`

Comment: codeMagic is right, you should probably do something more than setting them as null.  However, if all you want is to make this code run, setting them to null should suffice, because you're checking whether they're null a few lines later.

Comment: Yes it did ;) Thanks all! And sorry for the late answer.

But now i've got a new problem with the division... it crashes because when i divide 5 by 3 for example, since the answer is a float it will crash... Is there anyway of doing a cast or something like that?

Comment: Generally, you cast like so: "float fNumber = (float) iNumber;"   However, if you're making a calculator you should probably be treating all input as floats in the first place.  Anyway, please mark this answer as "accepted" and post a new question if you run in to any more roadblocks, and good luck!